# How to put Object into a panel?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, panel

So I have a list of Object, with a random height and weight. I also have a random number of those objects into a variable.

What I'm trying to do is to print all those object into the correct panel (I have 2 panel).

First of, my GUI and Object class (Blocks) are 2 separated class. Into the GUI, I'm doing this :

```
    private JPanel initPanelBloc() {
    panelBloc = new JPanel();
    bloc = new Bloc(false);
    panelBloc.add(bloc);
    return panelBloc;
    }
```

My Bloc class :

```
public class Bloc extends JPanel{
private int hauteur, largeur, nombreBloc;
private boolean premierPassage = true;
private ArrayList<Bloc> listeBlocRestant;
private Random rand = new Random();

public Bloc(boolean premierPassage) {
    this.hauteur = 10 + rand.nextInt(50 - 10);
    this.largeur = 10 + rand.nextInt(50 - 10);      
    listeBlocRestant = new ArrayList<Bloc>();
    if(premierPassage == true) {
        this.nombreBloc = 5 + rand.nextInt(30 - 5);
        insererBlocList();
    }
}

public ArrayList<Bloc> insererBlocList(){
    premierPassage = false;
    for(int i=0; i<nombreBloc; i++) {       
        Bloc bloc = new Bloc(false);
        listeBlocRestant.add(bloc);
    }
    return listeBlocRestant;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics2D g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.fillRect(10, 20, this.largeur, this.hauteur);   
}
```

I've got also a 3rd class where I call the GUI class :

```
    public Optimisation() {
    this.aff = new InterfaceGraphique();
}
```

And its in the above class where I need to do what I want.

I did not write in this what I want to do because I still don't know how to do it. Should I create a for each loop and take the list of blocks and for every blocks I want them to be print on the panel, with an x and y (of the fillRect) change between blocs ? I'm really lost, I tried to think about this yesterday but still no clue..

Cordially

Comment: See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). The `DrawOnComponent` example  shows you how to paint a List of Rectangle objects onto a panel.

Comment: well, I'm lost lol I do not understand everything in there since its with the click and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm lost lol I do not understand everything in there since its with the click and so on

Well, the clicks are really not relevant to the painting concept.

The painting concept is you store the object you want to paint in an ArrayList. Then in the paintComponent() method you iterate through the ArrayList to paint each object.

In my example you have a method `addRectangle(...)` which adds one Rectangle object at a time. You can manually add a Rectangle by invoking this method without using a mouse. This allows you to add Rectangles of a different size/location/color.

For example you just change the code as follows:

```
private static void createAndShowGUI()
{
    DrawingArea drawingArea = new DrawingArea();
    drawingArea.addRectangle(new Rectangle(10, 10, 200, 100), Color.RED);
    drawingArea.addRectangle(new Rectangle(210, 110, 20, 100), Color.BLUE);
```

Now the red rectangle will appear when you run the code.

The key points are:

1. you need a way to add the object you want to paint to your class
2. you then need to paint these objects in your paintComponent() method. You can't hardcode the painting the way you are currently doing it.

In your code your `Bloc` object will need to contain the information needed to paint the bloc.

Comment: hmm I see. So in my case, I already store the object into the ArrayList `listeBlocRestant`. So now, what I need to do, its to do something like this : `for(Bloc bloc : listeBlocRestant.contains(bloc))` then, for each bloc, I need to call a function to draw that in the panel ? I'm really sorry if I take time to understand, I'm trying to study new things..

Comment: `So in my case, I already store the object into the ArrayList` - yes, but it looks to me like all Bloc object are created with the same properties, so when you attempt to paint them you will only ever see one Bloc. You need a way to differentiate one Bloc from another. Maybe you need to add a method to the class to change a specific Bloc and its properties.  `I'm trying to study new things`No problem. You took the time to read the suggestion and ask a follow up question. Seems like you understand the big picture now.

Comment: `Bloc object are created with the same properties` they don't have the same size, as you can see, I'm doing that : `this.hauteur = 10 + rand.nextInt(50 - 10); this.largeur = 10 + rand.nextInt(50 - 10);` (hauteur means height and largeur means width). Its not enough ?

Comment: `they don't have the same size` - missed that.  If your logic is to just have the "size" property of your block, then as you iterate through the ArrayLIst you need to manage how each row it is painted and when you need to wrap to a new row yourself. You are in full control of the properties of each Bloc object and the painting of each Bloc.

Comment: So if I understood well, I need to do that :                                               `public void drawRect() {
  for(Bloc bloc : listeBlocRestant) {
   //here I call the function addRectangle which draw it in the panel ?
  }
  
 }
 
 public void addRectangle(Rectangle rectangle) {
  //draw the Rectangle in the panel ?
 }` I don't really know how to put that well as a comment lol, its hard to read like it is

Comment: You don't need an addRectangle() method. That was MY method to add a Rectangle to a List of ColorRectangles to be painted. My ColorRectangle class contained the location/size and color of the rectangle. Your Bloc is  my ColorRectangle class. Your Bloc contains only the size of the object you want to paint. So now you need need to add logic to dynamically calculate the "location" of each Bloc, since it appear that you want your Blocs to be painted in a row until you reach the width of your panel and then you start a new row.

Comment: Thats what I did.. I'm pretty sure there is so much mistakes since its a "huge" function for me.. [link](https://pastebin.com/tkC8TcFU) I did it on pastebin because it will be incomprehensible here

Comment: `I'm pretty sure there is so much mistakes` - well that is what debugging is for. So start slowly. Try adding only one Bloc to the List and paint that object. Then you add a second object and make sure you can paint two on the same row. Each new Bloc will keep the same "y" value, but the "x" value with change.  Then you add a few more to force wrapping. When wrapping occurs you need to increase the "y" value and reset the "x" value to 0. You debug your code each step of the way. I'm not going to comment on your code because I can't execute it.